# How do I uncomment lines in an XML file using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, comments

I can comment lines easily enough with Ctrl+Shift+Q.
How do I uncomment the lines?  Ctrl+Shift+K doesn't do it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you have the **XML Tools** plug-in, you can use the following shortcuts for block commenting/uncommenting:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> — comment selection
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> — uncomment selection.

As for the Ctrl+Shift+K shortcut not working, you should probably report the problem to the Notepad++ developer.

**Edit**: Looks like the standard *Block comment* (Ctrl+K), *Block uncomment* (Ctrl+Shift+K) and *Toggle block comment* (Ctrl+Q) commands don't work with XML at all. (I'm using v. 5.5 by the way.)

Comment: Maybe Ctrl+Shift+k has been remapped.

Comment: No, I haven't found any other command with this shortcut assigned. The appropriate menu command (Edit -> Comment/Uncomment -> Block uncomment) also doesn't work, so it must be a problem with Notepad++.

Comment: For me, Ctrl + Alt + Shift + R was dual mapped to "Launch in Chrome". I ended up deleting that shortcut since I'll use it far less often.

Comment: Very useful plugin - works fine on v 5.9.3, except when you alt-select columns of text.

Answer (score 24):

The Notepad++ comment/uncomment functionality is not really intuitive. Here's a list of the comment shortcuts and related operations that Notepad++ provides:

- **Ctrl-Q**
  Toggle line comment on current line / selection
- **Ctrl-Shift-Q**
  Create block comment on current line / selection (no toggle!)
- **Ctrl-K** 
  Create line comment on current line / selection
- **Ctrl-Shift-K**
  Remove line comment from current line / selection

Now, since XML only has block comments and no line comments, the only way to create a comment is to use *Ctrl-Shift-Q* and there is no way to remove a comment as Notepad++ does not provide a *Remove block comment* feature.

Igor

Comment: Still true in V 5.9.3

Comment: Looks like there's a block uncomment feature now (6.8.8), but there's no default shortcut key.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-K works only when the cursor is inside an xml element.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl-Q
uncomment on current line / selection

Ctrl-K
comment on current line / selection

Comment: Why did you copy/paste (partially) previous answer?

Answer (score 1):

I had the situation to remote comments from a properties / ini file.

used the reg expression ^.*#.*$ to search and replace with blank (see here
http://www.shareaschnitzel.com/delete-a-line-containing-certain-string-or-text/ )

next steps remote blank lines.

This might help you to remove comment from a text file