# How to delete multi-line comment in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

I have an XML file saved in Notepad++ and I want to delete multi-line comments
(from `<!--` through `-->`). 
How can I do this globally (without going line by line)? 
For example,

```
<Text>
<Text1>Hello</Text1>
<Text>
<!--<Text1>Hello</Text1> commented section
<Text> commented section
<Text1>Hello</Text1>--> commented section
<Text>
<Text1>Hello</Text1>
```

Comment: Do you just want to uncomment all multiline comments only, leaving normal comments?

Comment: Please read [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
and [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html). [Edit] your question when you get stuck after you have tried something yourself.

Comment: I want to delete all multi line comments

Answer (score 0):

[According to this answer](https://superuser.com/a/139232/885475) notepad++ doesn't have this functionality with XML. Possibly use another editor that does, just to perform that function.

I'd suggest vim with the [tcomment plugin](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim), but I presume you're unfamiliar with vim so that may be tricky to use. VSCode may be more intuitive for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use replace with this regular expression:

```
<!--.+-->
```

and an empty replacement value. Check ". matches newline"